# How to refresh entity using ember data

Tags: ember.js, ember-data

In my aplication I recived with websockects info about with objects are changed and ember data should reload them.

How can I force emberdata to update already loaded record?
How can I force emberdata to get know from server that some records are already delted?

Comment: The official solution here -  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14181223/polling-an-ember-data-record-is-there-a-way-to-do-it

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/q/14181223/90741

Answer (score 2):

The only way I could find to achieve something like this is to trigger manually `App.store.loadMany(data)` with the json (if you have it), or performing a `App.store.findQuery(App.Model, {})`, which will invalidate your cache.

I opened an issue a few days ago on ember to ask about this:

https://github.com/emberjs/data/issues/245

It seems like they're working on this case scenarios - ember/data is still quite young!

Comment: ok this seems be good, but it's still problem with inform the store about already deleted model.