# emberjs data refresh already loaded data

Tags: ember.js, ember-data

i can't seem to be able to refresh data that has already been loaded into the store.
i found a possible solution here but it doesn't work for me.

[How to refresh entity using ember data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10563384/how-to-refresh-entity-using-ember-data)

when i tried to do this App.store.loadMany(data) i get this error

"Uncaught Error: DS.StateManager:ember563 could not respond to event setData in state rootState.loaded."

when i tried to use this App.store.findQuery(App.Model, {}) i get findQuery is not defined.

i'd prefer to use this approach App.store.loadMany(data) if possible.

i appreciate any help. thank you!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i ended up modifying ember-data.js using this solution here

https://github.com/emberjs/data/pull/106

it works for now.