# How to reload an ember data record?

Tags: ember.js, ember-data

I'm using the new router and ember data rev 11.

I have a need to force ember-data to re-load data for a record from the server. Using `App.MyRecord.find`(2) in `setInterval` function loads the data from the client local store.

How can I reload the data from the server?

Comment: Are you looking for this? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10563384/how-to-refresh-entity-using-ember-data?rq=1

Comment: Yes, I looked at it and many other places, including internal API. It doesn't work. My Model is: App.Channel.find('ch_66'). The request to the server is /channels/ch_66 which is SHOW request (get specific channel with id='ch_66'). When using findQuery('ch_66') requests the server /channels?ch_66 which is INDEX request (get all channels)

Answer (score 55, accepted):

I [just pushed](https://github.com/emberjs/data/commit/278a0b863f0b1b2494fe2319ac12be6167195f6b) `record.reload()` to Ember Data. This will ask the adapter to reload the data from the server and update the record with the new data.

#### Constraints:

- You can only call `reload()` on a record if it has completed loading and has not yet been modified. Otherwise, the returned data will conflict with the modified data. In the future, we will add support for a merge hook to address these sorts of conflicts, which will allow `reload()` in more record states.
- If you call `reload()` and change or save the record before the adapter returns the new data, you will get an error for the same reason. The error currently looks something like `Attempted to handle event 'reloadRecord' on <Person:ember263:1> while in state rootState.loaded.updated.uncommitted.`. Basically, this means that your record was in the "updated but uncommitted" state, and you aren't allowed to call `reload()` outside of the "loading and unmodified" state.

Comment: Curious, does the state of the record change while reload() is loading? I forget if there's a state when the object is initially loading that prevents it from being modified...if so could it use a similar substate in the reload() case that would obviate constraint #2?

Comment: Yehuda...this seems to be refreshing the record, but it's not updating the UI like I would expect. Is there something that needs to be called to apply changes to the record to the UI?

Comment: @commadelimited If your record is dirty, the view will not rerender. A [get()](https://github.com/emberjs/data/blob/v1.0.0-beta.6/packages/ember-data/lib/system/model/attributes.js#L221) will return the locally modified value. You can however do a `yourRecord.reload().then(function(record) { record.rollback() })`

Comment: is there any news on possibility of a `merge` option for reload? or giving override priority to either the local or remote version of the model?