# How can I force ember-data to refresh an object after committing it?

Tags: ember.js, ember-data

I'm submitting an object to our API via a POST and then transitioning to a route that displays that object.  The API modifies one or more fields in the object in the POST and returns the updated info in the request response.

The data displayed is the original data from before the POST to our API.  I can see from the console that ember-data is receiving back the updated information from our API.  How can I force ember to "refresh" the object so that it displays the correct info?

Answer (score 3):

Matt. Yehuda Katz posted a reply to a user which provides this functionality:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/14183507/506230

Basically you create a record, apply it, save it, then reload it.

```
saveMessage: function(text){
    var acct = Social.Account.find(this.get("id")),
        msg = Social.store.createRecord(
                    Social.Message,
                    {
                        text: text,
                        account: acct,
                        created: new Date()
                    }
                );

    acct.get("messages").addObject(msg);
    Social.store.commit();

    var timeoutID = window.setTimeout(function(){
        __msg.reload();__
        console.log('reloading');
    }, 250);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

It turns out ember was actually behaving properly and no additional work was necessary.  The problem is that I was setting a variable on the controller with the same name as a computed property on my model.  The value of the variable on the controller was being displayed rather than the computed property.  Changing the name of the controller variable resolved the issue without any additional code.