# Ember model reloading in interval

Tags: ember.js, ember-data

I have a User model, which has latitude and longitude properties, which are used to show current user location on map.

```
App.User = DS.Model.extend({
    firstName: DS.attr('string'),
    lastName: DS.attr('string'),
    email: DS.attr('string'),
    jobs: DS.hasMany("App.Job"),
    latitude:   DS.attr('number'),
    longitude: DS.attr('number'),
    measuredAt: DS.attr('date'),
});
```

What is the best way to autoupdate latitude and longitude properties from server every given interval? Does ember-data support this kind of use case? I can't find any samples with this functionality. I think I will need to override find method for User class with setInterval in it, is this the right approach?

Thanks

Answer (score 8, accepted):

For those who are coming across this question now -- don't use `setInterval`, it's been shown to cause serious memory leaks.

Use Ember's own [Ember.run.later](https://www.emberjs.com/api/ember/2.15/namespaces/Ember.run/methods/later?anchor=later) instead.

See also:

- [SetTimeout vs. Ember.run.later in an ember app?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21505332/settimeout-vs-ember-run-later-in-an-ember-app)
- http://guides.emberjs.com/v1.12.0/cookbook/working_with_objects/continuous_redrawing_of_views/
- https://www.slideshare.net/yoranbe/presentation-31170160

Edit: Feb 3, 2019 - Update broken links.

Comment: +1 for using the Ember run loop instead of a willy nilly setInterval. This should be voted up or at least incorporated into the chosen answer.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I will accept this one as correct.

Comment: voting up for bringing up [ember run loop](http://guides.emberjs.com/v2.0.0/applications/run-loop/). I believe that understanding run loop is the most empowering bit of learning a beginner can do

Comment: @DmitryMatveev all your links are 404

Comment: @aandis - Thanks for the heads up, I updated the links.

Answer (score 9):

EDIT: Please see Dmitri Zagidulin's answer.

So I figured it out. For now all I need was to override didLoad method on model, in future I will probably need more complex solution, but this is adequate for now.

```
didLoad: function(){
  var self = this;
  setInterval(function() {self.reload()}, 5*60*1000); //every 5 minutes
}
```

In case someone needs to reload more models, good solution would be to implement this as Mixin.

Answer (score 5):

The model has a `.reload()` method now, which you could use in a `setInterval` callback. See https://stackoverflow.com/a/14183507/363073

P.S. Watch [#545](https://github.com/emberjs/data/issues/545).

Comment: I'm curios to know: where does `setInterval` come from?