# How to observe on properties and clear them on reload

Tags: javascript, ember.js, handlebars.js, ember-data

I'm reloading data for a view every 4 seconds with this

```
var App = Ember.Application.create({
    ready: function() {
        setInterval(function() {
            App.Quotes.find().reload
        }, 4000);
    }
});
```

And I'm fetching the value in my view with this:

```
    <blockquote>
    {{#each model}}
        <p>{{message}}</p>
    {{/each}}
    </blockquote>
```

**Question**

Every 4 seconds a new request is fired off to the REST API to grab a new quote. However, that new quote is getting appended to the existing quotes. How can I overwrite the old quotes and only display the new, changed, value?

Answer (score 0):

See [Ember model reloading in interval](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15618666/ember-model-reloading-in-interval) and possibly make the minor change:

```
didLoad: function(){
  var self = this;
  setInterval(function() {
    self.clear(); // <- this clears out the existing record
    self.reload();
  }, 4000);
}
```

It's a bit odd to me that you are doing this in the Ember.Application object instead of an array controller. Is there a reason for doing this?