# EmberJS: Load a teaser of a model for a list, full model for detail view

Tags: ember.js

Anyone figure out how to partially load a model for one view, then load the entire model for another?

For example:

```
  /*
    This will get all projects, so we only want an id and name returned from the server.
    Each project is a monster, so we don't want all data for each project.
  */
  App.ProjectsRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
    model: function () {
      return App.Project.find();
    }
  });

  /*
    This is a project detail, so we'd want the entire model returned from the server. Embedded records and all.
  */
  App.ProjectRoute = Ember.Route.extend({

  });
```

The closest thing I could find is this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/14183507/1125563

In that I can do something like this:

```
  App.ProjectRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
    setupController: function(controller, model) {
      if (model.get('isTeaser')){
        model.reload();
      }
    }
  });
```

In this workaround, I have a computed property isTeaser that checks a few things to determine if I've only partially loaded it.

Other than being a little messy, the only deal breaker here is that it's transitioning to the route with a partially loaded model and then after it's loaded, all the stuff will kind of in-elegantly snap in. Not a fan..

Am I missing something obvious?

Comment: did you have a look at the new **router facelift**? see here for more details https://gist.github.com/machty/5723945. I guess the changes introduced will help you solve your problem.

Comment: You're right - that will help a lot. I'm thinking the afterModel hook will let you see if it's complete, if not, re-fetch it and then the promise would be resolved.. Which RC is that facelift in (or is it not out at all)

Comment: it' already in RC6 :)

Answer (score 1):

Here's my approach which eliminates the initial rendering delay. Is that what you meant by 'inelegant snap in'?

```
// Load the light version of all subjects on page load
App.ApplicationController = Em.Controller.extend({
  init: function() {
    return App.Subject.find();
  }
});

// Fetch all our previously loaded subjects
App.SubjectsRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
  model: function() {
    return App.Subject.all();
  }
});

App.SubjectRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
  // If we're loading the page directly to this route, do a normal find
  model: function(params) {
    return App.Subject.find(params.subject_id);
  },
  setupController: function(controller, model) {
    // Show what details we have for this subject (e.g. the title) immediately
    controller.set("model", model);

    // Load full details for the model and display them as soon as they arrive
    if (Em.isEmpty(model.get("text"))) {    
      App.Subject.find(model.get("id")).then(function(model) {
        return controller.set("model", model);
      });
    }
  }
});
```

Comment: This is helpful, though if you have many routes, I can't see loading everything up front in init to solve the problem. That said, I didn't think of using init to pre-load my models and then use all(). Thanks for suggestion!

Comment: @drgizzlemd `if (App.Subject.all().length == 0) App.Subject.find()` perhaps?