# With Ember.js handlebars templates, how can I link to the full url of an object to force a model reload?

Tags: ember.js, handlebars.js

I currently have this template

```
{{#each model}}
    {{#linkTo object this}}{{name}}{{/linkTo}}
{{/each}}
```

which creates

```
<a href="path/#/objectid"/>
```

This does not cause a model reload, but a page refresh with that url does.
How can I make a link in my template with a full url?

```
<a href="path/objects/{{id}}">{{name}}</>
```

does not work, because {{id}} does not seem to fully resolve inside the quotation marks, so I get something like:

```
path/objects/<script id="metamorph-5-start....
```

I have seen answers hinting at adjusting setupController, but what if I do not want to reload the model every time? It would be nice to have control over this from the templating side, i.e. using {{#linkTo}} when no reload is needed and some other trick when a reload is needed. Is there an easy way to create a full url based on model parameters in handlebars?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out - although without changing the url, so I am still using a normal `{{#linkTo...}}`.

As mentioned in [How to reload an ember data record?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14181223/how-to-reload-an-ember-data-record/14183507#14183507), record.reload() can be used - it works for me like this:

```
App.ObjectRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
...
  setupController: function(controller, model) {
      var record = App.Object.find(model.id);
      record.reload();
      controller.set("model", record);
  },
});
```

If there was an easy alternative using a modified url, I would still be interested in finding out.

Answer (score 3):

This is may not be a full solution to your problem, but as for this part:

> does not work, because {{id}} does not seem to fully resolve inside the quotation marks, so I get something like:

there is help:

```
<a href="path/objects/{{unbound id}}">{{name}}</>
```

Using [`unbound`](http://emberjs.com/api/classes/Ember.Handlebars.helpers.html#method_unbound) does not put the script metamorph tag's around the property.

Hope it helps you to tackle down your problem.

Comment: Thank you - this certainly answers the part of my question about creating a urls without metamorph tags.

May I ask a follow-up question? I have an ember-data-compatible backend that provides JSON-encoded object details for "baseurl/objects/ID". If I link to "path/#/objects/{{id}}" the object is displayed appropriately in my template but without querying the backend, hence no details. If I link to "path/objects/{{id}}" I just get the raw JSON. How would you change the url and/or what would you add in App.js to integrate the raw data into the template?