# Emberjs: Periodically reload ArrayController data from RESTAdapter

Tags: ember.js

I have a default `ArrayController` with a simple view like this:

```
{{#each}}
  <li>{{name}}</li>
{{/each}}
```

and a trivial route

```
App.PostsRoute = Ember.Route.extend
  model: ->
    @store.find("post")
```

The data is loaded from a HTTP source using a `RESTAdapter`. How do I periodically reload it from the server, including removals, new objects and changes?

I'm new to emberjs and don't really know where to start. I found a [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14181223/how-to-reload-an-ember-data-record) discussing `Model.reload()`, but I don't see how that will help for new objects and removals. Also I'm not sure where to put the `setInterval` so that it's only active while I'm on the right view (something that [this](http://awardwinningfjords.com/2011/12/27/emberjs-collections.html) doesn't do properly).

Answer (score 0):

I set up a global clock object (similar to http://livsey.org/blog/2013/02/20/tick-tock/), and added an observer on `clock.minute` in my route to reload the collection:

```
App.PostsRoute = Ember.Route.extend
  model: ->
    @store.find('post')
  reload: (->
    @store.find('post')
  ).observes('clock.minute')
```